# What is altermagnetism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, terminology

Since 2022, I have come across [several papers](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=altermagnetism&searchtype=all&source=header) on [Altermagnetism](https://journals.aps.org/prx/edannounce/10.1103/PhysRevX.12.040002), a novel phase of matter that breaks time reversal, but without a net magnetization. It also has many other interesting properties.

What is altermagnetism? Why is it interesting, and what are its potential applications?

Comment: What you do not understand from those sources?

Comment: @Mauricio I do understand what it is. I asked this question so that this site will have a generic discussion about altermagnetism, like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/466393/60646) or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327934/what-is-so-special-about-spontaneous-symmetry-breaking-time-reversal-example?rq=1). So far, there are no other posts about altermagnetism on this site.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi This is not a discussion site, but rather a Question-and-Answer site. Post are not meant to spur discussions, but rather to solicit answers to clear and well-formulated questions. You are certainly allowed to ask questions to which you already know the answer, but the questions must be clear and direct. In particular, answers to the current version (v2) of this question could fill many pages, so it would be better to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I know that this is a question-answer site, and when I wrote "discussion", what I really meant is, "some elaborate answers" (I admit my choice of words in the previous comment could be confusing). This site has many great and detailed answers that actually fill several pages, and questions that can be answered in varying degrees of depth (e.g. [What's inside a proton?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81190/60646)), and in my opinion, that is perfectly fine.

Comment: Some specific questions receive answers very naturally as users are enthusiastic about certain topics. However I will say that most of the questions in this site need some motivation, just posing the question and dropping some sources is not enough. It would be better if you could write up a small summary of what you understand, then others users can fill the gaps and add more.